# Release & Versions maven plugin

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

we have a problem with maven releases and maven version plugin. In Jenkins we want to do releases automatically upon pressing a button. To remove snapshot dependencies we want to use the maven versions plugin. Suppose we have two projects A (latest release 0.0.1, latest snapshot 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT) and project B with a dependency on ProjectA - 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT and we want to release project B. How can we upgrade project Bs dependencies to the latest available release version? The maven versions plugin goal "use-releases" does not change the 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT dependency because there is no 0.0.2 release version of this project.

So my question is: how can we automatically remove snapshot dependencies and replace them with the latest available release version in our scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Using maven-release-plugin should be enough. There are two steps `release:prepare` and `release:perform`. When you do `release:prepare` settings those args `developmentVersion` and `releaseVersion` what would do the plugin is remove the SNAPSHOT for the current release (use `releaseVersion`) and then prepare for your next development iteration (use `developmentVersion`) and other things like commit in your SCM and tag the code.

For more information you can take a look [maven-release-plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html).